# Rewriting an infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, economics

I was reading [this economics article](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-03-microeconomic-theory-and-public-policy-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT14_03F10_lec18.pdf) (page 2), and I was curious about how to go from
$$ DPV \space w(1)=w(1)+\frac{w(1)}{1+r}+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^2 }+...+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^\infty }$$
to this part
$$DPV\space [w(1)\times\frac{1}{1+r}]=\frac{w(1)}{1+r}+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^2 }+...+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^\infty }$$
$$DPV\space [w(1)\times\frac{1}{1+r}]=w(1)$$
$$DPV\space [w(1)\times (1-\frac{1}{1+r})]=w(1)$$
$$DPV\space w(1)=w(1)\frac{r+1}{r} $$

(DPV is the discounted present value, and $w(1)$ is the wage after 1 year of education).

Answer (score 0):

Something useful to know is that $d=u (1+r)^{-1} $ grows to $u $ after one period since $d (1+r)=u $. So $d $ is the duscounted present value of $u$.

The sum -DPV of a perpetuity of $w (1) $- is a geometric series and sums to $w (1)(1+r)/r $).

Comment: What about this step:
$$DPV\space [w(1)\times\frac{1}{1+r}]=\frac{w(1)}{1+r}+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^2 }+...+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^\infty }$$
$$DPV\space [w(1)\times(1-\frac{1}{1+r})]=w(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ DPV \space w(1)=w(1)+\frac{w(1)}{1+r}+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^2 }+\cdots+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^\infty }\tag 1$$
Multiplying the LHS and the RHS by $\frac{1}{1+r}$ we have
to this part
$$
\begin{align}
DPV\space w(1)\times\color{red}{\frac{1}{1+r}}&=\color{red}{\frac{1}{1+r}}\times\left[w(1)+\frac{w(1)}{1+r}+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^2 }+\cdots+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^\infty }\right]\\
&=\frac{w(1)}{1+r}+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^2 }+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^3 }+\cdots+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^\infty }\tag 2
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting $(1)$ and $(2)$ side by side we have
$$\begin{align} DPV \space w(1)-DPV\space w(1)\times\color{red}{\frac{1}{1+r}}=w(1)&+\left[\frac{w(1)}{1+r}+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^2 }+\cdots+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^\infty }\right]\\&-\left[\frac{w(1)}{1+r}+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^2 }+\cdots+\frac{w(1)}{(1+r)^\infty }\right]
\end{align}
$$
that is
$$\begin{align} 
DPV w(1)\;\underbrace{\left[1-\frac{1}{1+r}\right]}_{=\frac{r}{1+r}}=w(1)
\end{align}
$$
and finally
$$ 
DPV w(1)=w(1)\frac{1+r}{r}
$$